# Straight Forward Trigger - Custom Object Update Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, update

I'm still pretty new to APEX and wanted to see if you could help.  I think its pretty straight forward.

I have a custom object called **Interest** which contains two custom fields.  I want to update the **opportunity** with those fields **when an Opportunity is created**.  There is a **look-up relationship from the Interest to the Opportunity.**  Interest records (already have the relevant fields populated) and are automatically associated with opportunities when an opportunity is created.

**All I want to do is update the opportunity fields with the fields from the interest object.**

Many thanks for your help in advance!

**Custom Object : Interests**
API Name:  Interest__c

**Fields on Interest Record**
Label Name: Core Lead ID 
Api Name:  Core_Lead_Id__c
Label Name: Core Instance ID 
API Name: Core_Instance_id__c

**Fields on Opportunity** 
Label Name: Core Lead ID 
Api Name:  Core_Lead_Id__c
Label Name: Core Instance ID 
API Name: Core_Instance_id__c

I want to populate the opportunity fields upon creation of the opportunity.  Not sure it matters however users create opportunities automatically when they convert Leads to a Person Account and Opportunity.  (YES I SAID PERSON ACCOUNT)

Comment: TobyDog - welcome to SFSE. Community etiquette is to try the task yourself and then, if you get stuck, post relevant sections of code (snippets please) and errors encountered - then you will then get help. SFSE members tend not to want to do the coding for others without demonstration of effort on your part.

Comment: Hi there!  Thanks for the tip.  I will definitely do so in the future.  I had attempted all the other options of formula fields and workflow rules but kind of don't know where to begin with the APEX.  I am currently learning it and so will have a place to start next time!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to write trigger anymore for such processes. Just use "Process builder" or alternatively try if you work it out by simple workflow. But I am very process builder can do this.

plus you do not need apex skills.

Answer (score 0):

Given your criteria it seems that there should be a one to one relationship with opportunity? If so, you may want to modify the object model to have the opportunity Lookup to the interest object then:

Since the Opportunity has a lookup to the Interest object, simply create formula 
fields for the required information.

If this is not possible then you will have to write a trigger or use Process Builder...